# C++ unique_ptr<Base> to point to ptr of Derived

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class, unique-ptr

I have the following code:

```
class Base{
public:
    virtual void do_something(int a) = 0;
    virtual ~Base();

};

template<typename T>
class Concrete : public Base{

    T _t;
public:
    Concrete(){};
    virtual void do_something(int a);
    virtual ~Concrete();
};

template<typename T>
void Concrete<T>::do_something(int a){
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
template<typename T>
Concrete<T>::~Concrete(){}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {


    std::unique_ptr<Base> b(new Concrete<int>());
    b->do_something(5);
}
```

However, the linked exits with an error. The output is:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Base::~Base()", referenced from:
      Concrete<int>::~Concrete() in testbed_evaluator.o
      Concrete<int>::~Concrete() in testbed_evaluator.o
  "typeinfo for Base", referenced from:
      typeinfo for Concrete<int> in testbed_evaluator.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I can't figure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: `~Base()` is not implemented.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You promised the compiler a destructor for `Base`, so it made calls to it.  But then you never wrote one, so when the linker sees those calls it doesn't know what to do.

You can fix it as easily as changing

```
virtual ~Base();
```

to

```
virtual ~Base() {}
```

The latter has a body; it's a real definition.

Answer (score 3):

Please define base class destructor

```
virtual ~Base() {}
```

Refer following example 
http://ideone.com/0PNWN6

Answer (score 1):

I got your example to compile and run by:

1. Including iostream:

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   ```
2. Removing the virtual destructor ~Base() which was never given an implementation.  The other thing you could do is provide a no-op implementation, like so:

   ```
   virtual ~Base(){};
   ```
3. Using a standard pointer with the 'new' keyword:

   ```
   int main(int argc, char **argv) {      
       Base* b = new Concrete<int>();
       b->do_something(5);
    }
   ```

Those things will get your example to work.  If I may, let me comment on the templating.  Your implementation expects that doSomething() will always use an int.  However, templates are used when you want to make your implementation flexible enough to work with any type.

Comment: Removing the virtual destructor is not an acceptable solution, `std::unique_ptr<Base>` needs it, as would `delete b;` which is missing from your manual memory management example/.